# Do Condominium Owners have standing to build on Condominium common areas?

Tags: florida, construction-law

It is my understanding that licensed contractors are required for construction in Florida.

What are the exemptions and what is the governing rule?  Assume the context is:

- a condominium's common area
- substantial construction, where in a failure results in significant safety risk or damage

Are there any circumstances under which owners (members of the Condominium) build substantial improvements (for example a wooden deck or a concrete patio) on common area?

Comment: Can you offer more detail? I would be very surprised if an individual owner was allowed to build anything on a common area. It might become more murky if is was actually a [limited common area](https://communityassociations.net/limited-common-element/).

Comment: Standing is not the same as legal right. Hiring a licensed person to undertake construction is not the same as doing the construction yourself. What is your question?

Comment: Is there an HOA? Your question title says 'condominium owners' and those folks typically don't have rights to alter things that are in common areas.

Comment: Assume there is an HOA and not limited common area.  Question appended to original posting.

Answer (score 1):

No, individual owners cannot make any alteration to the common elements of the condominium. The responsibility for the maintenance or improvements of common elements is entirely under the control of the HOA. Unless otherwise specified in the condominium declaration material alterations or improvements to a common element requires a vote of the HOA, and 75% of the voting interests of the HOA must approve any substantial modification or improvement. This is set forth in the Florida statutes: [718.113 Maintenance; limitation upon improvement; display of flag; hurricane shutters and protection; display of religious decorations.—](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0718/0718.html)

If it was a limited common area (a common area who's use is reserved to one unit) it might be more ambiguous. Some condo declarations might allow owners to make some improvements to a limited common element: say enclosing a balcony or installing a heat pump.

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  The construction is a wooden deck or patio on the common area (not limited common area).  I think you are indicating that the approval of said improvements ultimately requires approval of 75% of the HOA.

Comment: That is the default in Florida law. The condo declaration may modify this, but I can't image any declaration would permit an owner to do this unilaterally.